# Proving convexity of a function

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Given that $f$ and $g$ are convex functions, I'm trying to show that $H_{\alpha}$ given by $H_{\alpha}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x)+g(x)+\sqrt{f^2(x)+g^2(x)-2\alpha f(x)g(x)}$) is also convex for all $\alpha\in[0,1]$. However, I find that proving this directly from the definition of a convex function is extremely tedious. Can anybody provide a more elegant approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why the $1/2$ is needed.

Comment: Well of course, $f+g$ part is not needed also. But this is the problem I got. And maybe it affords some geometric interpretation.

Comment: why do you think the $f+g$ part is not needed?

Comment: The presence of the $1/2$ may be explained by the fact that $H_1(x) =\max(f(x),g(x)$.The presence of the $1/2$ might be explained by the fact that $H_1(x) =\max(f(x),g(x))$.

Comment: If the functions $f$ and $g$ non-negative then $H_\alpha(x)$ can be interpreted as a semiperimeter of a triangle with sides of lengths $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and an angle $\varphi$ between these sides such that $\cos(\varphi)=\alpha$.